# Excel VBA looping multiple columns to find if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Good Afternoon,

Hope everybody is doing well.  I have a sheet that is over 3k rows that 50 columns that I'm trying to grab info from.  I need to check multiple columns to see if any of them have a yes in them.  If so I need to display yes in on cell.  I haven't had much experience with looping.  I've been looking for a good while and just can't figure this one out.

When going through one column of information I was using the following type of code:

```
Sub Item()
Dim Num as long
Dim cell as range

Num = 5

For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet 1").Range ("A5:A4102")
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Num, 1).Value = cell.value
        Num = Num + 1
    ElseIf cell.value = ""
        Num = Num + 1
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

I just can't figure out how to get this kind of thing to check multiple columns in one row and kick back a value before moving onto the next row.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to check 50 columns in each row. If there's a yes in any of those columns, put a yes in column A. You could use the `Range.Offset` property. You loop through column A, but offset to each of the 50 other columns to check the value. Here's an example.

```
Public Sub Item()
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    For Each rCell In Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A5:A4102").Cells
        For i = 1 To 50
            If rCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "yes" Then
                rCell.Value = "yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next rCell
    
End Sub
```

For 3,000 rows and 50 columns, this won't take long to run. If it got bigger, there may be better ways than checking each column individually.